# FlexContext.getServletContext() is returning NPE

Tags: java, apache-flex

I'm having an issue with Flex.

The following java line is throwing NPE.

```
ServletContext servletContext = FlexContext.getServletContext();
```

However, the following command works just fine and throws no exception.  After the command executes, httpServletRequest is null (as expected).

```
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = FlexContext.getHttpRequest();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer.  I think that Flex pulled an abstraction on us.  I think that getServletContext() actually calls FlexContext.getServletConfig() within the method.  Because of this internal call, when Flex then internally calls getServletContext (), the method throws NPE.

I simply altered the code to the following.

```
ServletConfig servletConfig = FlexContext.getServletConfig();
if (servletConfig != null) {
    ServletContext servletContext = servletConfig.getServletContext();
}
```